# PDO's lastInsertId for MySQL a race condition?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm writing a PHP class file which pushes data to a MySQL database using PDO. Essentially the file gets hit many times very quickly (creating a new instance of the class each time), and the lastInsertId() method isn't keeping up. For example:

```
//sleep(rand(100,1000)/100);
$sql = "INSERT INTO `testing` (`name`, `timestamp`) VALUES (?, ?)";
$this->dbh->beginTransaction();
$sth = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindValue(1, $_POST["name"]);
$sth->bindValue(2, microtime());
$sth->execute();
$this->id = $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
$this->dbh->commit();
```

If the page is called twice very quickly, when `$this->id` is returned both instances have the value of 2, despite the DB looking like this:

```
+----+--------+-----------------------+
| id | name   | timestamp             |
+----+--------+-----------------------+
|  1 | Mark   | 0.98705900 1385770566 |
|  2 | George | 0.99367300 1385770566 |
+----+--------+-----------------------+
```

The problem is that the first query executed should have an `id` value of 1, and the second query executed should have an `id` value of 2. To get around this, I added a random sleep (commented out above) and it corrects the issue. I am using transactions, which I believed would rectify this issue. Am I missing something obvious here?

For those curious, here's my table setup:

```
CREATE TABLE `testing` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `timestamp` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

PHP 5.3.3
MySQL 5.1.69

Comment: What do you mean by "both" having the same value? Both what?

Comment: Each time the PHP file is called, it instantiates a new instance of the class.  In this case, the file is called twice, so two instances of the class are created. After the above code is executed, both instances have the same value for their `id` attribute.

Comment: What it looks like is that you are trying to put something more accurate than microtime , right ?

Comment: No, `microtime()` is just there to show that the queries are executing very close together. The problem is that if two queries execute at the same time, query 2 gets inserted **after** query 1, but **before** query 1 retrieves the lastInsertId. Therefore, the DB gives query 1 the ID number belonging to query 2 (since query 2 was the lastInsert). Query 2 also gets the ID belonging to query 2, since it was the lastInsert.

Comment: Is the table perhaps backed by a non-transactional storage engine (like MyISAM), and are the successive INSERTs perhaps sharing the very same database connection?

Comment: Please, show your `create table`

Comment: Updated post with the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: The only reason I can see for that behavior (even if it sounds unlikely) would be if both inserts happened on the same PDO object/connection. How is `dbh` set up before getting to this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that Chromium's built-in console's network tab does not show the correct information. Showing the ID via console.log() works as expected, and using FireBug for Firefox shows the network activity as expected. I was working under the assumption that the network tab would show the actual network activity, which it does not always.

Answer (score 9):

MySQL does not return one session's last insert id to another session.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id says:

> The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis. This means that the value returned by the function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column by that client. This value cannot be affected by other clients, even if they generate AUTO_INCREMENT values of their own. This behavior ensures that each client can retrieve its own ID without concern for the activity of other clients, and without the need for locks or transactions.

---

Re your comments:

This has been the behavior of MySQL since the beginning. Returning the last insert ID would be pretty useless if it were susceptible to a race condition, that is if inserts in other sessions could pollute your session.

One possibility is that you're using persistent connections, because old versions of PHP had a bug that a connection could be given to a new PHP request and grant access to sessions-scoped state from a previous PHP request. In other words, things like locks and transactions and temp tables and user variables and last insert id could survive to a subsequent PHP request. These problems should be resolved in PHP 5.3 with the mysqlnd driver; a persistent connection should be "reset" to an initial state.

Another possible explanation is that it's really functioning correctly, and you're mistaken in your observations. So I'd suggest testing it carefully and methodically.

**update:** according to [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20302784/20860), this problem had nothing to do with MySQL or PDO or lastInsertId. It sounds like you weren't seeing discrepancies in output of your PHP code at all, you were seeing unexpected numbers in network performance stats in Chrome Dev Tools.

Comment: But how can that explain my problem? It seems to directly contradict what I'm experiencing. I actually did read this while investigating, and since this is **not** how it is acting for my code, I posted here.

Comment: Additionally, I did list my version as being 5.1.69, rather than the version your link references (5.6). In this situation, however, the passages in question are the same.